# Style of a TextBox: Why is 'AcceptsReturn=true' not applied?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, custom-controls

I have a custom control in WPF, which consists of a toggle button, a TextBlock and a TextBox. What I basically want to do is to show the TextBox when the toggle button is checked and the TextBlock otherwise. Furthermore I want allow defining to style properties on the control via dependency properties, which are applied to the TextBlock and the TextBox at runtime. The default template looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type views:EditableLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type views:EditableLabel}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <DockPanel Margin="0">
                        <telerik:RadToggleButton x:Name="PART_Toggle" 
                                                 DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                                 IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsInEditMode, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ToggleImage}" Height="14" />
                        </telerik:RadToggleButton>

                        <TextBlock  x:Name="PART_TextBlock"
                                    Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text}" >
                        </TextBlock>

                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" > 
                        </TextBox>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The custom control has two dependency properties for styles, one for the `PART_TextBlock` and one for `PART_TextBox`. The styles are assigned in the `OnApplyTemplate` method of the custom control and in the property change callbacks of the two dependency properties:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _textBlock = (TextBlock) GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBlock");
        _textBox = (TextBox) GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox");
        _toggleButton = (RadToggleButton) GetTemplateChild("PART_Toggle");


        ApplyStyles();
        UpdateVisibilities();
    }

private void ApplyStyles()
    {
        if (_textBlock != null) _textBlock.Style = TextBlockStyle;
        if (_textBox != null) _textBox.Style = TextBoxStyle;
    }
```

(The callbacks are not shown here, as they are trivial, just calling `ApplyStyles()`.

I use the custom control like this:

```
<views:EditableLabel Text="{Binding SelectedToolbox.Description, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        CanEdit="{Binding SelectedToolbox.CanEdit}" 
                        ToggleImage="../Resources/Images/edit-26.png">
    <views:EditableLabel.TextBlockStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </views:EditableLabel.TextBlockStyle>
    <views:EditableLabel.TextBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Style>
    </views:EditableLabel.TextBoxStyle>
</views:EditableLabel>
```

Everything works as expected, except from the `AcceptsReturn` setter is not applied, which I find very strange. I've debugged `ApplyStyles()`: The style is assigned correctly and both setters are contained within the style.

`TextWrapping` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` are both set correctly:

[image: VSV]

while `AcceptsReturn` is not:

[image: ACR]

Any ideas, what might be the issue here?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why assign the styles in `OnApplyTemplate` instead of in the `EditableLabel` template?  e.g., `<TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" ... />`. Also, your screenshots indicate `AcceptsReturn` has a local value.  Do you have any code in your `EditableLabel` class that directly assigns the `AcceptsReturn` property?  If so, the local value you set will take precedence over style setters.  Use [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid changing the value source.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your answer! Actually, the first question is a good one, because I don't know, actually! I was dealing with the control's visibilities on the basis of some dependency properties in `OnApplyTemplate`, and just handled the styles the same. I've refactored it as you've suggested and: It works! Still, i don't understand why my approach doesn't work. I haven't set `AcceptsReturn` anywhere locally. If you post your answer as an answer, I will be glad to upvote and solve the issue :) Thank you!!

Comment: Hmm, odd indeed.  Oh well, glad I could help!  I added an answer.

Comment: while you said other setters (except `AcceptsReturn`) work, please notice that you checked it in a more reliable way. I mean the settings you've done in the Style may be actually ***the same as the default values***, so it might make you think it works for those setters. Try adding some more distinct and easy-to-recognize style, such as add a `Setter` setting the `Background` to `Red`. I doubt the whole style is not applied. Confirmation is a very important step to be sure there is something wrong in some way.

Comment: I've checked that, the style is being applied and the other setters change the behavior of the TextBox as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you posted suggests `AcceptsReturn` has a local value, i.e., a value set by explicitly calling the property setter or `SetValue`.  Do you have any code in `EditableLabel` which explicitly sets the `AcceptsReturn` property?  If so, the local value you set will take precedence over any style setters.  You can avoid this by using [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) to change the value while leaving the value source unchanged.

Secondly, rather assigning the style in your code behind, it is generally easier and more reliable to simply bind the style within the template, e.g.:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" ... />
```

You might try this first and see if you get better results.